# Cannot get negative float value from HEX in C#

Tags: c#

I have to read some hex data from a file. It works in C++ and Matlab but not in C# (which is the language I'm using).

One data is made of 4 bytes, per exemple : **d0bd a7fa**

In C++/Matlab I can get the right value : -1.3362

But in C# I get this : 62.663810729980469

Here here's the C# code I'm using :

```
int exp = 6;
b.BaseStream.Seek(pos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
uint getValAbs = b.ReadUInt32();
(the below formula comes from the file format)
float actualValue = (float)(getValAbs * (Math.Pow(2, exp - 32)));
actualValue = 62.663810729980469;
```

and in matlab its

```
Spec(:,isub)    = fread(fid,fnpts,'long') * pow2(subfexp-32);
```

and it gives me the right value...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
b.ReadUInt32();
```

They are using `'long'` that is *signed*, so

```
b.ReadInt32();
```

Comment: well... as always I thought that the answer was much more complicated... thank you very much, even tho I feel pretty dumb right now haha

Comment: @ZephCraw If you re-read your problem it was easy to see: you had a negative number `-1.3362`, but you multiplied two positive numbers: `UInt32` and `Math.Pow(2, something)`. There is a problem here :-)